# HTTP logs using tcpflow with grep, redirecting to a file don't work (empty file)

Tags: bash, ubuntu, grep, io-redirection

I want to log some specific HTTP requests that have a keyword, that are coming to a specific port. `tcpflow` works fine, but I can't write filtered results to an output file.

I don't understand why this command works flawlessly ('detect' is a keyword I am looking for) and shows only lines that I need.

```
tcpflow -p -c -i eth0 port 80 | grep detect
```

meanwhile, at the same time, this doesn't work at all. log.txt file is empty...

```
tcpflow -p -c -i eth0 port 80 | grep detect  > log.txt
```

I suppose it has something to do with binary output?

because this way it works, but it results in a huge file (I don't need so much data)

```
tcpflow -p -c -i eth0 port 80 > log.txt
grep log.txt --text detect
```

And It only works with `--text` attribute (without it says something about binary file format), and after several days the file can become really large.

Comment: Does it work with `grep --line-buffered`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Arkadiusz Drabczyk' comment.
It works with a demo like this:

```
sudo tcpflow -i eth0 port 8080 -c | grep -A 50 "detect" --line-buffered  > /tmp/tcpflow.log
```